# How to make fit a larger image into the small image view

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, image-resizing, drawinrect

I have the image view which has fixed size.
But I want to fit every size of image into this without stretching.

I tried this

In method resizeImage, I passed my selected image and
size of UIImageView.

```
 func resizeImage(image: UIImage, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
        image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height))
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage
    }
```

But this is not working, It is still returning the stretched image.

Please let me know what could be the proper solution.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure its resized? What happens if you draw in a smaller Rect?

Comment: I just tried to draw text on the image by this method and it works fine.
but this is not working with simple image.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is your `UIImageView`'s `contentMode` property. Like so:

```
myImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
```

This value will make sure that when you set the view's image, the image will fill the view as much as possible without stretching the image. You could also use `.ScaleAspectFill` to completely fill the view, but then your image will be cropped.

Comment: Yes I tried these konrad.bajtyngier.
But in my case these are not useful.
Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something else or your image is still stretched with this method?

Comment: My guess is that if this didn't work for you, you're not setting the clips to bounds to true.

Comment: @GopalDevra if you use this method you should not be using the one in your resizeImage function. Your function will always give you an stretched image as long as you don't respect the aspect ratio of the original image.

Comment: @HugoAlonso isn't `ScaleToFill` stretching and `ScaleAspectFill` cropping/clipping?

Comment: @konrad.bajtyngier sorry, my bad. I read it, and the **Aspect** word was invisible to me :)

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
```

When you do this, two things happen:

1. the image in the image view keeps the correct aspect ratio (i.e. it's not stretched),
2. The image fills the image view completely. If needed, the center part of the image is cropped. E.g. if your image view is square, and the image is a rectangle, then the image will be cropped to a square.

Comment: Thanks Macondo2Seattle
But I want to show the selected image without cropped area
Without any stretching.
ScaleAspectFill crop the image.

Comment: @GopalDevra what you are trying to do is like trying to fit a soccer ball inside of a square box. You will end up losing the rounded shape of your ball. It just doesn't fit.

Comment: @GopalDevra in that case @konrad.bajtyngier has the right answer. Using `.ScaleAspectFit` ensures that the image is not stretched, and is fully visible inside your image view.

Comment: @GopalDevra another option for you is to ensure that your images and image views all have the same aspect ratio. Then you can show your images without any stretch or cropping, and with no empty space around them.